# Trying to perform a factorial in assembly but causing stack overflow

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

Ok, so I am trying to test out a factorial program from my college book, and when I type it correctly as shown, it gives me a stack overflow error.

It happens at the line `push ebp`. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
.code
main PROC
    mov ebp,0
    push 3
    call Factorial
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf
    exit
main ENDP

Factorial PROC

    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    cmp eax,0
    ja L1
    mov eax,1
    jmp L2

    L1:
        dec eax
        push eax
        call Factorial

    ReturnFact:
        mov ebx,[ebp+8]
        mul ebx

    L2:
        pop ebp
        ret 4

Factorial ENDP
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just me or anyone else think that you missed a

`mov eax, [ebp+8]`

at the start of the function (after the prologue)?
You are not getting the argument from the stack before comparing it with 0.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the book had a stack going up (though, this is unusual). At the moment, it subtracts from ebp every time something is pushed, because the stack actually grows down. (This seems a little counterintuitive, but that's how its done in most computers)

So, what's happening, is that you're pushing 3 onto the stack at address 0, subtracting 4 from ebp, and having MAX UNSIGNED INT - 3 now in ebp. Which is out of the stack, so "stack overflow" or, accessing something not in your stack.

Comment: EBP is not the stack pointer, ESP is. Further, initializing the stack pointer with 0 is perfectly valid if memory locations starting at are accessible.  It is an old (realmode) trick to put the stack at the far end of the segment.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to pop the 3 into eax, otherwise, eax is uninitialized.