# Why do I get stack overflow when my assembly code is called form a procedure but not main?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

Here is the code In question:

```
push 5
call Factorial
```

When I call this from main like this:

```
main PROC
    push 5
    call Factorial    
    exit
main ENDP
```

My code works fine, But if I call this as:

```
main PROC
    call Binomial
    exit
main ENDP


Binomial PROC
    push 5
    call Factorial
Binomial ENDP
```

I get a stack overflow at `push eax`in the code below:

```
Factorial PROC
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    mov eax,[ebp+8]
    cmp eax,0
    ja L1
    mov eax,1
    jmp L2

    L1:
        dec eax
        push eax
        call Factorial

    ReturnFact:
        mov ebx,[ebp+8]
        mul ebx

    L2:
        pop ebp
        ret 4

Factorial ENDP
```

I can not figure out why, but when I call it from main, the Factorial procedure exits as it should and returns to main, but when it is called from Binomial, instead of returning back to Binomial, it goes back to Factorial...which I find very odd. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Didn't you just [ask the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30987704)?

Comment: no, that was all called from main....and I simply just left code out in the question you are referring to.

Comment: Presumably `ENDP` doesn't automatically add a `ret`, so your code falls through into `Factorial`. Insert a `ret` before `Binomial ENDP`.

Comment: Use the debugger to find what eax contains in the Factorial proc. I think you'll find you're not getting 5 off the stack and the previous stack's contents are affecting the result. Are you pushing a WORD of 5?

Comment: Oh, yeah, @Jester. I didn't notice that one.